# How to compare asymptotic Big-O notation?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I need to determine if a given Big-O notation is the proper notation for a given function. For example, $g(n)=2^{lg(n^2)}+n^2$ is $g(n)=O(n^2)$ or $g(n)=4^n$ is $f(n)=2^{O(n)}$. My first instinct for the first problem, is to take the limit of $2^{lg(n^2)}/n^2$ and if the limit is 0, then they are equal. However, I am not sure how to take the limit using L'Hopital's rule to resolve the numerator. Also, it does not seem as if a similar approach would work for the second problem, because there is Big-O notation in the function itself. How would I go about solving these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition of $lg$, $2^{lg(n^2)} = n^2$. so, $2^{lg(n^2)} + n^2 = 2 n^2 = O(n^2)$.

Also, note that $4^n = 2^{2n} = 2^{O(n)}$.

The easiest way to deal with this is to try to bring everything as an exponent and then compare the exponents.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer! I just have one quick related question. When there are no exponents, is there a similar way to prove that a given Little-O or Big-O notation is the correct notation for a function? For example, $g(n)=n ln(n)$ is ultimately $g(n)=o(n lg(n)$. As $lg(n) \ge ln(n)$ I'd think this is correct because $lg(n)$ would always upperbound $ln(n)$ but is there a straightforward way to prove this?